# svn remove file from repo and not working copy

Tags: svn, delete-file

I have a situation in which a file exists in both the repo and the working copy.
However, the file is different for each machine. How do I remove the file only from repository and not the working copy?

PS : I am on ubuntu, so I'm using rapidsvn/kdesvn/command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
svn remove --keep-local
```

Comment: Worked perfectly well. Thanks very much.